# Cannot pass quoted arguments to batch script shortcut when running as an administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have, what I believe, is a fairly straightforward use case for shortcuts on Windows 10 that isn't working for a reason I can't explain and it is giving me 0 helpful errors to determine what is going on.

I have a batch script that takes 3 arguments, does some things with them, and cleans up when it is finished. This works perfectly fine from an elevated command prompt. These arguments can get rather long (as some of them are path names) and are also repeated each time I run the same task again. I made some shortcuts to the batch file and added the arguments in the target (i.e. `C:\files\start.bat "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"`) and set the shortcut to run as administrator.

However, for some unknown reason, the script just won't launch correctly. A window appears and then immediately disappears. I've tried adding a pause to the end of the script, but that did nothing. I even wrote a new script which is simply

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
```

and this also **doesn't work**. The script *does* open and run when "Run as Administrator" is unchecked and also *when the arguments are not quoted*, but that doesn't work for me as I need the actual script to run with elevated permissions and obviously arguments with spaces must be quoted. I've tried using various combinations of `call` or `runas`, but the effect is always the same. **Once elevated, shortcuts to **any** batch file, anywhere on my system, regardless of if the path or any arguments themselves contain spaces will not open if the arguments are quoted.**

I doubt this could be intended behavior and I'm fairly certain I would have run into this issue before as this doesn't seem like a non-standard use case for shortcuts, but I have no idea what's going on and would love some help. I found one similar question here, but it is from over a decade ago and all the "answers" are simply non-answers.

Comment: I suspect that you created the shortcut incorrectly if even your test script with nothing but `echo`s fails. The best way to check this is to open a command prompt as administrator and run the script from there instead of double-clicking the shortcut. That way, the window will stay open and you can read what the error message is. Also, `start` is already a command so you should call your script something else.

Comment: Also, if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498087/administrators-shortcut-to-batch-file-with-double-quoted-parameters was the question that you found, then changing your shortcut target to `cmd.exe /c "C:\files\start.bat "arg1" "arg2" "arg3""` is the correct answer. I have tested this and can confirm that it works.

Comment: Choose another filename. `start` is a `cmd` keyword.